# PHP mail() trouble

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I'm trying to include a simple contact form in a WordPress theme I'm coding for someone (they want it functional without using any WP plugins, so I'm simply using PHP).

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php

include "../../../../wp-blog-header.php"; // include WP to be able to use some options

if (of_get_option('ss_contact_email', 'no entry' )) { // custom WP option
    $mailto = of_get_option('ss_contact_email', 'no entry' );
} else {
    $mailto = get_option('admin_email'); // WP option to get email address of the admin
};

$cc = "";
$bcc = "";
$subject = "[Contact Form] " .$_POST['subject']. ""; 

$vname = ucwords($_POST['user']);

$email = $_POST['email'];

function validateEmail($email)
{
   if(eregi('^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?$', $email))
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}


if((strlen($_POST['user']) < 1 ) || (strlen($email) < 1 ) || (strlen($_POST['question']) < 1 ) || validateEmail($email) == FALSE){
    $emailerror .= '';

    if(strlen($_POST['user']) < 1 ){
        $emailerror .= '<span class="wrong">Please enter your name. </span>';
    }

    if(validateEmail($email) == FALSE || strlen($email) < 1 ) {
        $emailerror .= '<span class="wrong">Please enter a valid e-mail address. </span>';
    } 

    if(strlen($_POST['message']) < 1 ){
        $emailerror .= '<span class="wrong">Please enter your message. </span>';
    }

} else {

    $emailerror .= "<span>Your message has been sent. Thank you!</span>";

    // NOW SEND THE ENQUIRY

    $timestamp = date("F j, Y, g:ia");

    $messageproper ="\n\n" .
        "Name: " .
        ucwords($_POST['user']) .
        "\n" .
        "Email: " .
        $email .
        "\n" .
        "Website: " .
        $_POST['url'] .
        "\n" .
        "Subject: " .
        $_POST['subject'] .
        "\n" .
        "Comments: " .
        "\n" .
        $_POST['message'] .
        "\n" .
        "\n\n" ;

        $messageproper = trim(stripslashes($messageproper));

        mail($mailto, $subject, $messageproper, "From: \"$vname\" <".$_POST['email'].">\nReply-To: \"".ucwords($_POST['user'])."\" <".$_POST['email'].">\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() );

}
?>

<?php echo $emailerror; ?>
```

Error handling seems fine, it returns all the correct errors but if all fields are correct it goes blank instead of sending and displaying the "Thank you.." message.

I've used the same script on the same server numerous times, and never had any problems with it but this time I stumbled upon an issue - the mail isn't getting send, even though it doesn't return any errors.

I'm not sure what goes wrong. Anyone able to skim through the code and look for some obvious mistakes?

Comment: Have you checked the server logs to see if the `mail` command is failing?

Comment: You might try making variables like `$subject` and `$message` to use throughout this snippet. Two reasons: it'll be easier to test more simply without the form submission, and you can more safely filter your `POST` data once to keep things a bit more secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using:

```
 strlen($_POST['question']) < 1
```

as a check in your if statement, but then using 'message' as a replacement. If 'question' is not set it will not try and send, but will also not print an error.

Comment: Bingo. Thanks a million. Always helps when someone else looks at the code after I've been staring and fiddling with it for ages :)

Comment: It's called 'rubber ducking'. Often just explaining your code in english to an inanimate object can help you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the email's not getting sent, most likely PHP is dying at the point of the `mail()` call. You're not checking the return value from mail(), which is bad form - never assume a call to an external service succeeded. Turn on error reporting, enable display errors, etc... then try the contact form again. check your server logs and see if anything shows up in the browser.

The code otherwise looks fine, so without any more information, this question is most likely unanswerable.